Problem with Adding Dependencies for Kotlin Parcelize and KSP Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' in Android Studio
Error Message
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9.24']
> Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'.
   > lateinit property target has not been initialized

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9.24']
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'.
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property target has not been initialized
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProjectExtension.getTarget(KotlinProjectExtension.kt:413)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProjectExtension_Decorated.getTarget(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProjectExtension.getTarget(KotlinProjectExtension.kt:412)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspConfigurations.decorateKotlinProject(KspConfigurations.kt:93)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspConfigurations.access$decorateKotlinProject(KspConfigurations.kt:14)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspConfigurations$1.invoke(KspConfigurations.kt:87)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspConfigurations$1.invoke(KspConfigurations.kt:85)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.KspConfigurations._init_$lambda$4(KspConfigurations.kt:85)

I tried to implement Kotlin Parcelize and KSP for the Room database. But when I add those two dependencies, this error appears.
This is my lins.versions.toml:
[versions]
activityKtx = "1.9.3"
agp = "8.7.0"
coreSplashscreen = "1.0.1"
coreTesting = "2.2.0"
datastorePreferences = "1.1.1"
espressoCoreVersion = "3.6.1"
espressoIdlingResource = "3.6.1"
fragmentKtx = "1.8.4"
kotlin = "1.9.24"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
kotlinGradlePlugin = "1.9.24"
kotlinxCoroutinesTest = "1.7.3"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.6"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.3"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
androidAsyncHttp = "1.4.11"
converterGson = "2.9.0"
glide = "4.16.0"
loggingInterceptor = "4.11.0"
mockitoCore = "4.4.0"
pagingRuntimeKtx = "3.3.2"
retrofit = "2.9.0"
navigationFragmentKtx = "2.8.3"
navigationUiKtx = "2.8.3"
ksp = "1.9.24-1.0.20"
roomKtx = "2.6.1"
roomPaging = "2.6.1"

[libraries]
androidx-activity-ktx = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-ktx", version.ref = "activityKtx" }
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-core-splashscreen = { module = "androidx.core:core-splashscreen", version.ref = "coreSplashscreen" }
androidx-core-testing = { module = "androidx.arch.core:core-testing", version.ref = "coreTesting" }
androidx-datastore-preferences = { module = "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences", version.ref = "datastorePreferences" }
androidx-espresso-idling-resource = { module = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource", version.ref = "espressoIdlingResource" }
androidx-espresso-intents = { module = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents", version.ref = "espressoCoreVersion" }
androidx-fragment-ktx = { module = "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx", version.ref = "fragmentKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-livedata-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-paging-runtime-ktx = { module = "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "pagingRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomKtx" }
androidx-room-paging = { module = "androidx.room:room-paging", version.ref = "roomPaging" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "roomKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
kotlin-gradle-plugin = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlinGradlePlugin" }
kotlinx-coroutines-test = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesTest" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
android-async-http = { module = "com.loopj.android:android-async-http", version.ref = "androidAsyncHttp" }
glide = { module = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide", version.ref = "glide" }
logging-interceptor = { module = "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor", version.ref = "loggingInterceptor" }
mockito-core = { module = "org.mockito:mockito-core", version.ref = "mockitoCore" }
mockito-inline = { module = "org.mockito:mockito-inline", version.ref = "mockitoCore" }
retrofit = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit", version.ref = "retrofit" }
retrofit2-converter-gson = { module = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson", version.ref = "converterGson" }
androidx-navigation-fragment-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigationUiKtx" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
kotlin-parcelize = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize", version.ref = "kotlin" }

This is my build.gradle (Project-Level):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.parcelize) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
}

And this is my build.gradle (Module-Level):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.parcelize)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.sateapalehgeurogokapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.sateapalehgeurogokapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField(...)
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Based Library
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)

    // Retrofit API
    implementation(libs.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.android.async.http)
    implementation(libs.logging.interceptor)
    implementation(libs.retrofit2.converter.gson)

    // Datastore
    implementation(libs.androidx.datastore.preferences)

    // Room
    implementation (libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)

    // Paging
    implementation(libs.androidx.paging.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.paging)

    //  UI Support
    implementation(libs.glide)
    implementation(libs.androidx.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.splashscreen)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)

    // Coroutine
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.ktx)

    // UI test
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    implementation (libs.androidx.espresso.idling.resource)
    androidTestImplementation (libs.androidx.espresso.intents)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

    // Unit Testing
    testImplementation(libs.mockito.core)
    testImplementation(libs.mockito.inline)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.core.testing)
    testImplementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.test)
}

I have tried clearing cache, invalidate cache, rebuild project, adding classpath. But nothing can solve my problem. What should I do? Please help me, thank you!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78141650/14162959 your answer is here! alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
